# Django & jQuery - How to use the TagSelectMultiple widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to use the [jquery-tagselector widget](http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/) from stackoverflow's user [Julio César](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2148/julio-cesar) with Django, and I am quite lost...

My form is:

```
class CreationForm(forms.Form):
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),widget=TagSelectMultiple(attrs={ 'style': 'width:400px', 'id': 'tags' }))
```

The TagSelectMultiple widget has the following code:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.util import flatatt
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.html import escape, conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class TagSelectMultiple(forms.SelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None: value = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        self.name = name
        output = [u'<div class="tagSelector" multiple="multiple"%s>' % flatatt(final_attrs)]
        options = self.render_options(choices, value)
        if options:
            output.append(options)
        output.append('<input type=text>')
        output.append('</div>')
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        if unicode(option_value) in selected_choices:
            return u'<span class="tag">%s <a>x</a><input name="%s" type="hidden" value="%s"/></span>' % (
                conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label)), escape(self.name), escape(option_value))
        return ''
```

And my Tag model is:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    word = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.word
```

In my template, I have included all the needed javascript files:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
<link href='{% static "jquery-tagselector.css" %}' rel=stylesheet>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='{% static "jquery-tagselector.js" %}'></script>
```

And I print my field with `{{form.tags}}`.

Following [Julio César instructions](http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/) on his webpage about how to use his Django Form Widget, I only had to modify the widget attributes, to get a good `input id` name:

Before my modification:

```
tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
        widget=TagSelectMultiple(attrs={ 'style': 'width:300px' }))
```

After my modification:

```
tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
        widget=TagSelectMultiple(attrs={ 'style': 'width:400px', 'id': 'tags' }))
```

**First question**: I don't know if I need to add the following script because I already gave my list of tags in the `queryset` attributes form field?

```
$('#tags').tagSelector(tags, 'tags');
```

**Second question**: When typing in my autocomplete box, I get absolutely no choices despite of having plenty `Tag` objects. Is it because of my tag model?  [Julio César](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2148/julio-cesar) don't explain the architecture of his `Tag` model, and I have some difficulties to guess this one. Or maybe it is because  there is no `self.choices` in the widget code?

**Link:**
javascript [jquery-tagselector.js](https://code.google.com/p/petprojects/downloads/detail?name=jquery-tagselector_v1.0.0.zip&can=2&q=) file

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help you, but when I need a `MultipleChoiceField`,  I prefer to use the library `select2` for javascript. Configure the `select2` with autocomplete and multiple fields is too easy. They have a very good documentation and examples here: [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: @Liarez   Your link is very interesting! I am gonna take a look to this wonderful library.